# Wrong date output of dynamic Rss feed

Tags: php, mysql, rss, mysqli

The example of following block of code that generates the rss feed dynamically can't print the date properly.

```
<?php $db = new mysqli("a", "b", "c", "d");
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'; ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
<atom:link href="http://site.com/rssfeed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<title>Test</title>
<description>Test Feed</description>
<link>http://site.com/rssfeed/</link>  
<copyright>Your Copyright Information</copyright>
<?php    $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$results = $db->query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$number = $results->num_rows;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) {
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();
$title = $row['title'];
$description = $row['description'];
$link = $row['link'];
$date = date("r", $row['date']);
?>
<item>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<description><?php echo $description; ?></description>
<link><?php echo $link; ?></link>
<pubDate><?php echo $date; ?></pubDate>
<?php /*?><guid><?php echo $link; ?></guid><?php */?>
</item>
<?php    }    ?>
</channel>
</rss>
<?php    $db->close();    ?>
```

The `table` columns are `id`, `title`, `description`, `link`, `date`

http://site.com/rssfeed/index.php doesn't give any date output at all called within `<pubDate><?php echo $date; ?></pubDate>` tag when the `date` value is inserted in the following way

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `title`, `description`, `link`, `date`)   
VALUES
(1,'Site || Home', 'http://www.site.com', 'http://www.site.com', 'TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
```

On the other hand when the `date` value is inserted in the following way, http://site.com/rssfeed/index.php prints wrong date (It prints only one wrong date for all available feeds) to all available dynamic feeds which is something like `Thursday, January 01, 1970 6:33 AM`

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `title`, `description`, `link`, `date`)     
VALUES  
(1,'Site || Home', 'http://www.site.com', 'http://www.site.com', '2012-05-07 02:16:46');
```

By the way, in create table statement column `date` was defined as following:

```
  `date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

The Rss validator gives the following recommendation during validation process

`Implausible date: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:33:32 +0100`

Why it's happening? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A mysql timestmap column will return its contents as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` string value, which you can **NOT** pass directly to PHP's date call. That requires a unix time stamp. If you must format the date on the PHP side, then you'll have to do

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) AS date FROM yourtable
```

instead. Alternatively, you could cheat PHP-side and use

```
$date = date("r", strtotime($row['date']));
```

or use the MySQL [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to convert it to your RFC2822 format

---

comment followup:

No, your insert timestamp string does NOT work:

```
mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> create table x (x datetime);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> insert into x (x) values ('timestamp default current_timestamp');
sQuery OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.43 sec)

mysql> select * from x;
+---------------------+
| x                   |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I've posted the whole syntax here. What shall be the whole sql query is this case? Your answer is vague. Nor that does guide to any solution neither leave any clue to learn something straightly. If I weren't new here I would cast a down vote for you. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is not a valid insert value. that's just a string. If you want the current timestamp, use the `NOW()` function.

Comment: I strongly disagree with you, a mysql timestamp `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` can be called to any PHP page simply by echoing it like `<?php echo $row['date']; ?>` in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format. The thing to consider here is that, the date / time can't be printed in any other expected  format unless some available php functions are used to format it. Well, in this case the problem arises since I suppressed a xml file with php, I guess.

Comment: No. In your insert query, you're using the literal text `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT ...`. That syntax only works in CREATE TABLE queries. For an `INSERT` query, you must use `CURDATE()` or `NOW()`.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` not only as the field value in `CREATE TABLE` statement but also as column value in `INSERT INTO`statement serves the same purpose like `CURDATE()` or `NOW()`. You can try it yourself. Well I disagreed with your very first `Answer`. You can read my previous comment, why? I re-quote a portion of my previous comment below: `I strongly disagree with you, a mysql timestamp like TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP can be called to any PHP page directly by echoing it like <?php echo $row['date']; ?> in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.`

Comment: See edit proving that you're full of it. the only reason you're getting a properly formatted date from your DB is because that's the default OUPUT format for a mysql datetime/timestamp field, and you INSERTED a properly formatted date/time value to begin with.

Comment: Well, if you replace `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` with `CURDATE()` or `NOW()` you will get the same output `0000-00-00 00:00:00` unless you insert date / time  into the database using a form and this is applicable for `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` too. The question here is, if a MySql timestamp like `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (There are several other MySql time stamps too those generate current time automatically except `DATETIME`) can be called to a plain php page directly and I proved your answer wrong.

Comment: In my case, as a `XML` file was suppressed with `PHP` the MySql timestamp was unable to generate it with usual PHP date / time call (XML follows UNIX timestamp but not MySql timestamp and that is an exception and this was what my question about.